# Set heap size for customer java application

Tags: java, jvm, heap-size

I have a java application for our customer, delivered as a single jar file.
A new feature ends in an OutOfMemoryException - the detected problem is the Heap Size, which is set to low.

The customer don't want to set the option Xmx by _JAVA_OPTIONS, because it would "affect other java applications on the system", so I have to find another solution for this.

Is there a (ideally for the customer invisible) possibility to set this option beside using a start cmd file with "java -Xmx2G -jar (...).jar" ?

Comment: The start cmd file is your best option.  It achieves what you require in a simple fashion, and does it with zero risk of breaking other applications.   IMO, it is preferable that this be customer visible so that they can tweak it if they want / need to.  (After all, your code is running on their hardware ...)